# Dynamic sparse matrix with Eigen?

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

I need a sparse matrix that can grow (or maybe shrink as well) over time, adding rows, columns, etc.

I understand that with a dense matrix, you might call conservativeResize with generous and exponentially growing sizes so as to avoid having to reallocate memory often and use Eigen::Matrix::block to extract the matrix of interest.

Is this how I should go about doing things with Eigen::SparseMatrix too? If not (which is probably the case), what is the best way to have a dynamically sized Eigen::SparseMatrix?